# Inserting nested XML data into mysql database

Tags: mysql, xml, database, nested

I have a mysql database with some tables and some .csv and .xml files. I have no problem inserting the csv files but I am having problems for two of my .xml files because they have nested attributes.
I know how to import these files using php but I would like to have only one .sql script importing all my files.

My TABLE looks like this

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| UserID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| LName       | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FName       | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UserPhoneNb | char(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| City        | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PostalCode  | char(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Street      | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| HouseNb     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and the xml file like this.

```
<users>
  <user>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <lastname>CROCHEMORE</lastname>
    <firstname>Abdel</firstname>
    <password>8308</password>
    <phone>0482642387</phone>
    <address>
      <city>Saint-Gilles</city>
      <cp>1060</cp>
      <street>rue Steens</street>
      <number>96</number>
    </address>
    <bankaccount>4506690518145656</bankaccount>
  </user>
  <user>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <lastname>BOURDON</lastname>
    <etc...>
  </user>
</users>
```

I initially tried something like this

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/my/file.xml'
  INTO TABLE ChargeUsers
  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<user>'
  (@ID,@lastname,@firstname,@phone,@city,@cp,@street,@number)
  SET UserID=@ID, LNAME=@lastname, FName=@firstname, UserPhonNb=@phone,
      Street=@street, City=@city, PostalCode=@cp;
```

This did work for all the fields outside of address, but not for the ones inside of address. This is because the address  field is nested and it seems not to be one of the three different formats listed in the [mysql LOAD XML documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).

Is there although any way to do this in pure sql (without php). Or is there an easy way to change my xml file so that it would work with juste a LOAD XML?

(Maybe there is a way using `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<address>'` instead of `'<user>'` ?)

Comment: You can use XSLT to transform your XML, but if you're already familiar with PHP that would be a much easier route to go.

Comment: So i found how to do this, for some weird reason I can acces all parameters except bankaccount when I use ```ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<address>'``` and I can access all rows except the ones inside of ```<address>``` when I use ```ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<user>'``` So I just use both identifiers once and then I make a join on the two tables (I also made a temporary table to store the data)